# Open a folder, write the top 100 words that appear on text files in the specified folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to code a class called `LexicalAnalyzer` and within this class I have to code the following functions based on a folder directory.
`gettop100words`: returns a `dictionary` of the frequency of the overall top 100 words found in the text files of the said folder, not caring for CAPS.

`get_letter_frequencies`: returns a `dictionary` of frequency of the letters (a-z)

How do I write this `LexicalAnalyzer` ?

Comment: The key to programming is to break down big problems into smaller ones, then break those down into even smaller ones. Eventually you'll have pieces small enough you can figure them out individually, then work to assembling those little bits into a complete program.

Comment: Take a look on [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: and to find the correct tools to do so, your sounds like file-io, dictionary and some itertools should be able to solve it:  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/filesys.html   &  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html  &  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict . Or you could whip out the big guns and go wiht panda or numpy. Have fun.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here. 
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  If you miss a class, you should make up the deficiency from reading and discussions with your teacher and classmates.

Answer (score 0):

Just do for loop inside of the file(text file ofc) and add every word and how many times it occurs and return the dictionary. To split words just add the whole text of the file in one string amd use split function to separate the words into list and loop through it and do the dictionary thing i told you at the begging.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use in `fileinput` to iterate over files
2. Use in `collections.Counter` for counting objects(words, letters)

### Example

**Environment:**

```
$ tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
└── file3.txt

0 directories, 3 files
```

**Data:**

```
$ tail -vn +1 /tmp/test/*.txt
==> /tmp/test/file1.txt <==
hello world
world foo bar egg
spam egg baz
end

==> /tmp/test/file2.txt <==
foo xxx yyy
qqq foo
eee ttt def
cmp

==> /tmp/test/file3.txt <==
Foo BAR
SpAm
```

**Snippet:**

```
import os
import fileinput
import collections

DIR = '/tmp/test'

files = [os.path.join(DIR, filename) for filename in os.listdir(DIR)]
words = collections.Counter()
letters = collections.Counter()

with fileinput.input(files=files) as f:
    for line in f:
        words.update(line.lower().split())

for word in words:
    letters.update(word)

# top 3 word
print(words.most_common(3))

# top 5 letters
print(letters.most_common(5))
```

**Output:**

```
[('foo', 4), ('egg', 2), ('spam', 2)]
[('e', 7), ('o', 4), ('y', 3), ('l', 3), ('q', 3)]
```